# Copying row from one table to another?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have these three tables for services, executed_services and a rating table, which rates the service. My rating table has a foreign key to executed_services, and so, I wanted to "copy" the service to be rated to the executed_services relation. I tried using the following procedure, but this select won't work, as it has to return only one result.

```
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO servico_executado (id, data_abertura, id_solicitacao, id_profissional) 
            VALUES (SELECT id, data_abertura, id_solicitacao, id_profissional FROM servico WHERE id = NEW.id_servico);
        DELETE FROM servico WHERE id = NEW.id_servico;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
```

So, what should I do to get all the values from one table and insert on another? Or is there other way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO servico_executado 
       SELECT id, data_abertura, id_solicitacao, id_profissional 
       FROM servico WHERE id = NEW.id_servico;
```

Do not use 'VALUES'. If you have more columns in the table, you can use null in the select statement for those missing columns.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think in it. Worked like a charm

Comment: I am glad you spent time for writing feed back. thanks. Believe me, you will use this 'insert into abc select .. from xyz' nearly 100 times in coming years.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very easily in one step with a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) with the following simple query:

```
WITH deleted AS (DELETE FROM servico WHERE id = $1 RETURNING *)
INSERT INTO servico_executado (id, data_abertura, id_solicitacao, id_profissional) 
SELECT id, data_abertura, id_solicitacao, id_profissional FROM deleted
RETURNING *;
```

There is no need to use PL/pgSQL. The `id` of the service moved is denoted by the placeholder `$1` in the above query.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'll stick with the other aswer, as it seems easier